# Consent SDK "Yes, continue to see relevant ads" button is missing, how to fix?

Tags: android, admob

Consent form does not get the "Yes, continue to see relevant ads" button, it seems it is removed because "providers" (adProviders) is empty, how can I fix this?
I am using "**Custom set of ad technology**" providers with two providers, Google and Facebook.

Comment: I have the same issue now. The button was there but then it disappeared

Answer (score 0):

After I rolled back to v. 1.0.0, the button appears:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.0'
```

The current version `1.0.8` seems doesn't show the "yes" button :(